# Predicting risk of rare event occurring

Tags: machine-learning, extreme-value

Let's say I have a dataset containing a list of car accidents and associated information (e.g. weather, driver info, car state etc.).

Let's assume I know the number of cars on the road and the distribution of the relevant characteristics (e.g. number of male / female drivers, historical weather data etc.).

I would like to create a model to predict the risk of accidents given the current environment and the information about the driver.
It does not have to be precise (i.e. low/medium/high risk would be enough).

How should I proceed with that?  I cannot think of any standard machine learning technique to predict the risk/probability of a rare event such as a car accident occur.

Comment: You don't have any information on cases with no accidents? Can you provide a simple (possibly made-up) dataset to illustrate the situation you have in mind. Be aware that people may think this question is too broad to be answerable.

Comment: Thank you @gung for your comment. I only have statistics on the cases with no accidents, so I could potentially generate fake data that reflects those statistics. However, I do have real data only on accidents, as data was gathered only when accidents happened. The dataset is actually quite simple, each row would contain a set of features, such as time, location, speed of car, weather and so on.

Comment: I don't see how you can predict when an accident will occur if you only have data on accidents & not on their absence. (By fake data, I meant only for posting here to illustrate your situation, not for using to predict actual accidents.)

Comment: What I meant is that I have statistics about the distribution of cases with no accidents, so that I could potentially generate artificial data to represent those cases.

Comment: @MDG Still, you should edit your question to add more details on your problem, telling us also what kind of data do you have (possibly with example) etc.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will try to post a more detailed question next time.